# DatagridView get data from ms-access 2 different table

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a `2 ms-access table` like that:

```
student                     library
----------------------      ----------------------
|ID  | Name | Address |     |s_ID   | book | date |
|10  | John | add1    |     | 20    | book1| 03   |
|20  | Joe  | add2    |     | 30    | book2| 05   |
|30  | User3| add3    |     ----------------------
```

SO I want all that data in one single `datagridview` like that:

```
datagridview1
----------------------------------
|S.N | ID  | Name |  book  | date |
| 1  | 10  | John |   -    |  -   |
| 2  | 20  | Joe  | book1  | 03   |
| 3  | 30  | User3| book2  |  05  |
```

I tried this:

```
dim i as Integer = 1
sql = "SELECT ID, Name FROM student"
cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
If Not reader.HasRows Then
   DataGridView1.Rows().Clear()
ElseIf reader.HasRows Then
   Do While reader.Read
      Dim row() As String = {CStr(i), reader.Item(0), reader.Item(1),"",""}
      DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
      i += 1
   Loop
End If
```

I don't know how to do further.

How can I get that? Or any other methods?

Any help is appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

**Try this out**

```
  Dim sql As String = "select  row_number() over (order by ID) as S.N, ID, Name, book, date from student left outer join library on id=s_id"
    Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    connection.Open()
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "ID")
    connection.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
```

Comment: I want to take those data from two different sql  `select` command and join them in `Datagridview`. Can you help me how can I do that ?

Comment: you mean that two sql command is uded ? like select *from table1
select *from table2 is it ?

Comment: yes ! like `select * from table1` and insert those data on `datagridview` and same like `select * from table2` and also insert in `datagridview`.
I don't know If this is possible or not to insert on datagridview cells like that.

Comment: @PradipDhakal, whay you're suggesting doesn;t make any sense. If you want to populate one `DataGridView` then you can only have one data source, i.e. one `DataTable`. If you want to populate one `DataTable` from two database tables then you do that with a single query that includes a join. You've been shown how to do that. Now do it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm just wondering If this is possible by any other methods. That's all.

Comment: If you were just wondering that then you should have said that you were just wondering, rather than that you wanted todo it a different way. Why would you want to do it a different way if you've been given a perfectly good way to do it? Why does it even matter if it's possible by any other method? Unless the other method is specifically better, what's the point?